# Load Balancer Response time is more as compare to Elastic Search Latency

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, amazon-elb

We have an Elastic Search Cluster with 3 data nodes and 3 master nodes. We have exposed this Elastic Search with ELB in front of it.

Our Elastic Search Latency is 22-40 ms ( AWS elastic Search only consider query time not fetch time). Our Load Balancer Response time is ( 4-6 seconds).

How we can reduce this response time of the Load Balancer? What is the possible wrong configuration we might do?  Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Is your 22-40 actual latency or response time?

Comment: Do you really need the load balancer? There are some situations where it makes sense, but often times it just adds latency and complexity.